# Android AsynchTask in Linear Layout - Method must be called from UI Thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using AsynchTask in my app to save a record to a server.

The method that I use in my doInBackground doesn't do anything at all with the UI but I'm getting the following error

Method tryThis must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker

Like I said nothing was happening that involved the UI. So I've stripped back my code to try to identify the problem and it is now pretty much bare.. see below

You will notice that rather than the AsynchTask code being in an extension of Activity it is in an extension of LinearLayout as I am using this is for a custom view. I strongly suspect that this is where the root of the problem lies but I don't understand why and nor do I know how to get around it.

```
public class ExerciseView extends LinearLayout {

    public ExerciseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private class saveRecordTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String returnString = "";

            try {
                returnString = tryThis();
                //
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return returnString;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //startProgress();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
            // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in
            // progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
        }
    }

    public String tryThis() {
        String hi = "hi";
        return hi;
    }

}
```

I guess I could use an interface in the custom view to give the data to the Activity at the right time and then do the AsynchTask in the Activity but I'd really like to keep everything together in the custom view to minimise the amount of code that needs to written each time I use it.

Comment: Does this code still give you an error?

Comment: Please post a full stacktrace, and the snippet where you're executing the AsyncTask.

Comment: @MikeM. This error is occurring in Android Studio so I haven't got as far as compiling it or even writing the which executes it.

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It would help.
If you want to call tryThis() inside UI thread call it as following

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        tryThis();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to run it inside the UI thread, though. There is no need for it to run on the UI thread. I want it to run in my doInBackground()

Comment: If the system tells you the method must be called from the UI thread, then it must.  Your opinion on whether the UI is involved is irrelevant.